# Heroku downgrade php 7.3.* para 7.2.*

Tags: php, laravel-5, php-7, heroku

Não sei como fiz upgrade da versão do php no heroku para a versão 7.3, no entanto esta versão (7.3.*) está a causar vários bugs na aplicação, com faço para poder fazer downgrade para a versão 7.2.* ?

Já tentei alterar a versão no composer.json para:

```
"require": {
"php": "7.2.*",
```

Mas ao fazer deploy é instalada a versão 7.3 na mesma

Answer (score 1):

O meu composer.json estava incorrecto, alterei par ao seguinte:

```
"require": {
"php": "~7.2.11",
```

Mais informações sobre versões aqui: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#next-significant-release-operators